# $fn.yiiGridView.update calls for multiple grids

Tags: ajax, yii

In a view, I display two grids with data.
The user is able to submit data in the following way:

1. The data is sent using a form displayed in the same page
2. On submit, the form data is sent through an ajax call to a controller
3. The ajax call has a callback on success that executes

   ```
   $.fn.yiiGridView.update("grid1");
   $.fn.yiiGridView.update("grid2");
   ```

   as both grids will have their data changed by the submitted form.

The $.fn.yiiGridView.update method will update the grids by retrieving the same page and extracting what is required.

In this particular situation, it will happen twice, which raises the need to find a way to avoid this extra call and reduce unnecessary traffic.

Is there a way to modify the yiiGridView callbacks to update both grids with a single call?
I've tried to hack the methods, but with no success.

Comment: this is a good question. I think it is not possible by default as each grid "lives its own life". But what you could do is rewrite the onSuccess function, and do the extracting manualy

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think that's also a solution. Finally, I have found a solution that avoids extra scripting.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, after some struggle I have found a solution.

I realise that there's a field called ajaxUpdate that in the yiiGridView documentation (jquery.gridview.js line: 39) says :

> ajaxUpdate: array, IDs of the containers whose content may be updated by ajax response

This value is extracted from the CGridView parameters (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#ajaxUpdate-detail)

So I defined

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'grid1', //or could be grid2
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'ajaxUpdate'=>'grid1,grid2', //string separated with commas
    ......
));
```

and now just by calling

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update("grid1"); //or grid2 if you set ajaxUpdate in grid2
```

both grids will get updated.

I wonder if there's a way to override the value using the options parameter for the gridview function (using the $('#grid1').yiiGridView('update',options) syntax)

Comment: What do you mean by "override the values"? You can add GET parameters with "options" like this:         $( '#grid1' ).yiiGridView( 'update', {
            'data' : {
                'get_parameter_name' : 'value',
            },
        } );